# Like button on fan page does nothing after permissions redirect

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-like

Im developing a custom tab "tailgater of the week" where users can upload a photo and others can vote. Except I need to block access to users that are not fan. How I have the application now is as follows:

1) User (non fan/non permission granted) arrives at the tab and views contestants.

2) User feels the need to vote or upload, so user clicks on a button that says "Cast your vote/Upload your photo now" which will then redirect the user to a permissions page.

3) User then accepts the permissions and is redirected to a non-fan page (only way to really know if user is a fan) where the user is prompted to like the page.

4) This is where im having problems - User then presses the like button and the Facebook page does not refresh.

When the user refreshes all is A-OK but i'd rather not have them do an extra step, need to keep them interested.

5) the proceed to vote or upload and everyone is happy. (except me).

Is there any way around this? It seems the permissions page does something during the redirect or ... ? Im clueless, have been searching for days!

One thing that i did notice is: once the user is redirected back from the permissions page. the url gets this:

> &state=321608018ea1c0bc0e449ebcb12345d3&code=AQBy13WknCcof7FjfigjHaDrGd7zn-LbqMD5n_Lta4-whrHIKLYdF889qmzW3sQBZUegMUp8etYs5AgZHPmpB7jMKfpOgKJLtEjZbXYhZjn76GX3kFxX1HoxWIcyHRvMWLd9tUDAN1Ke6NSdeAFqF6mQIF8NJiLsl_jGqILvHdKW5nnLVfv40XHWO--d1TO2aTc#*#*

Once its removed the like button works perfectly.

Is there a way of getting around this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should get the user's to like the page before asking for permissions? This is the more common user flow. You can tell if the user likes the page by inspecting the signed request. More here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/